# `flip` arguments of infix application inline

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

Given a function for infix usage:

```
let f a b = (a+10, b)
f 4 5
=> (14,5)
4 `f` 5
=> (14,5)
```

The arguments can be flipped by defining a helper function:

```
let g = flip f
4 `g` 5
=> (15,4)
```

Is it possible to do this inline?

```
4 `flip f` 5
=> parse error on input `f'
4 `(flip f)` 5
=>  parse error on input `('
```

---

My use case is `Control.Arrow.first`. Instead of

```
(+10) `first` (7,8)
(17,8)
```

I would prefer a forward-application-style solution like

```
(7,8) `forwardFirst` (+10)
```

without needing to write

```
let forwardFirst = flip first
```

Comment: What's your use case for wanting to do this, given that you have defined `g` already?

Comment: Just added my use case. :)

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you can write it as `(7,8) & _1 %~ (+10)` using lens. Of course, you can just use `&` and  write it as `(7,8) & first (+10)`. Is this something similar to what you want?

Comment: Yes, this looks good, but having Lens as a dependency for something that small seems a bit hard to me.

Comment: Writing a single tiny helper function is definitely better than adding a dependency :)

Comment: I agree, but just defining `(&) = flip ($)` and using it as `(7,8) & first (+10)` would be better than defining a flipped version of every function.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the [HaskellWiki article on infix operators](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Infix_operator),

> Note that you can only normally do this with a function that takes two
>   arguments. Actually, for a function taking more than two arguments,
>   you can do it but it's not nearly as nice

The way to do this in your case would be something like this:

```
let f a b = (a+10, b)
let h a b = (f `flip` a) b
let a = 3
let b = 2
f a b = (13,2)
a `h` b = (12,3)
```

Comment: With `g = flip f` and `h a b = (f 'flip' a) b` both functions are the same. Where is the advantage of the more complicated version `h`?

Comment: Fair point. I'm not really sure if there is a better way to do what you want though.